# Update cfselect without form submition

Tags: onclick, cfwindow

I have a cfselect which is binded to a query using ajax proxy.
I do a update and addition of new values corresponding to the cfselect 
in a cfwindow of mine
I want the user to get always the latest and updated list in the 
cfselect. Is there a function which i can invoke in the onclick and intern will refresh the cfselect.
Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arasu,

It is a big coincidence that I too had a similar sceario to be dealt with. However it goes like this.

The solution is: ColdFusion.Bind.assignValue(,, )

I have my cfselect which is bound to a query. The values associated to my bind query is updated in another page of my website (in your case a cfwindow). so I too need my users to get the latest set of values in the cfselect each time they select it. so here comes the magic. I invoke the ColdFusion.Bind.assignValue(,,) in the onClick of my cfselect, where:

name: name of the control (here it is the cfselect name) you want to be binded

attribute name: the attribute of the control to assign the values to

function: function responsible to bind data to the control.

My code goes:

```
<cfform style="align:centre" id="frm_drpDwnBus" name="frm_drpDwnBus"> 
 <cfinput name="hdnrr" value="#rrSbstring#" type="hidden">    
 <cfselect name="dpDwnBs" bindOnLoad="true" 
  bind="cfc:getCalculatorData.getAllBus(hdnrr.value)" 
  value="busType_id_pk" 
  display="busType_name" 
  queryposition="below" onclick="javascript:refresh(hdnrr.value)" >
 <option value="0" on>Select a Bus</option> 
 </cfselect>
</cfform>
```

And my javascript code is:

```
<cfajaxproxy cfc="Calculator.getCalculatorData" jsclassname="cfcCalcu">
var dataCalcu= new cfcCalcu();
function refresh(s)
{
ColdFusion.Bind.assignValue('dpDwnBs','value', dataCalcu.getAllBus(s))
}
```

Now what I would recommend you to do is invoke the 'refresh' function when you have done any update/deletion in your cfwindow code. this would update the binding to your cfselect.