# Populate SELECTLIST with AJAX

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, cfc

I've asked this question recently but have been unable to get a solution. So I've simplified my question in an attempt to get just the critical part of my question answered.

I have a selectlist as follows:

```
<select name="descriptionDD4" id="descriptionDD4">
  <option value="add_new">ADD NEW</option>
</select>
```

I have a CFC as follows:

```
<cfcomponent>
  <cffunction name="getDescriptions" access="remote" output="false" returntype="query">
    <cfquery name="customDescriptions" datasource="#datasource#">
      select description
      from service_descriptions
      where description <>"ADD NEW"
      order by description
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn customDescriptions>
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

How can I populate this selectlist with the data returned by the CFC using an AJAX call? What would the code look like? This is what I've come up with so far:

```
<script>
                    $(document).ready(function CheckAjaxCall()
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                            type:'POST',
                            url:'cfcs/get_descriptions.cfc',                    
                            data: {'method': 'getDescriptions'},
                            success:function(data){ 

                                jQuery("##descriptionDD4 option").remove();
                                jQuery.each(data, function(i, item) {
                                jQuery("##descriptionDD4").append( "<option value="+ i +">" + item + "</option>" );
                            });

                            },
                            //error:function(){alert("Connection Is Not Available");}
                        });

                        return false;
                    });
            </script>
```

I realize that ColdFusion has the BIND and QUERY attributes for CFSELECT, but in my case, I must have a way to populate the list using AJAX.

Comment: The BIND and BINDONLOAD attributes create an Ajax reqeust to connect the form object to the data returned by a CFC function.

Comment: @Adrian - Yes I understand that, but need to be able to call the AJAX request that populates this list when a different AJAX call completes successfully. That is why I need to use an AJAX request, not a bind, to populate this list.

Comment: Can you try to write some basic javascript/jQuery first, then come back with specific questions? This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Actually, this isn't really a CF question at all. Yes, the CF is the backend, but all you need is a basic jquery ajax call.  Google a tutorial.

Comment: Maybe this will help - [ColdFusion UI the Right Way](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way) This project contains several examples of how to replace the built-in ColdFusion UI tags with regular JavaScript equivalents.

Comment: I've updated my question to include my current attempt at the JavaScript code.

Comment: Why the return false?

Comment: Not sure, thought I needed it.

Comment: This questions was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553467/populate-cfselct-with-ajax/25576481#25576481) by another post I have up, thanks to Leigh.